# How to autowire a bean inside a class that is not a configured bean?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Forgive me if I don't get the terminology correct.

My situation is thus:

I have a class, let's call it TheClass. Inside this class is a TheData object.

I have XML to set up the TheData bean, like so:

```
<bean id="theData" class="com.abc.TheData">
        <property name="field" value="value1" />

    </bean>
```

and a setter inside TheClass like so:

```
public void setTheData(TheData theData)
{
     this.theData = theData;
}
```

My problem is that if I don't also create the TheClass bean in the XML (and thus can't let it get autowired), it won't know to autowire the theData field (right?). And due to certain restrictions, I can't configure TheClass in the XML (and thus later have it autowired). So, my question is, how can I make this work? I'm a bit of a novice so if I'm missing something, feel free to point it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can get hold of the Spring context, cast it to `AutowireCapableBeanFactory`, and pass your instance of `TheClass` to the `autowireBean(Object)` method. Spring will then try to apply its autowiring rules to that object.

You'd need to add `@Autowired` to the `setTheData` method, though.

Comment: I ended up just creating a context and then using the ACBF to create the bean I needed. There's only one bean I needed autowired, so that seemed essentially equivalent. Since TheClass is instantiated entirely outside of the scope of Spring, that seemed like the only option (and it works), even if it does tightly couple things. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use @Resource or @Component.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. I think you misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

I just now saw this question and thought I might add one more method of doing what you want (although the AutowireCapableBeanFactory would be my choice).
You can leverage the @Configurable annotation in the manner that is described in [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/spring-configurable-magic.html) blog post

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to just use the @Autowired annotation on your instance variable that your setter is setting, without having to declare a TheClass bean in your XML.  That is:

```
public class TheClass {
  @Autowired
  private TheData theData;
}
```

Comment: Can you annotate your TheClass class with @Component, @Repository, @Service, or @Controller?  It should be picked up, then, I think, as long as you have <context:component-scan base-package="your.classes.package"/> in your XML configuration.

Comment: Let me try that and get back to you in a bit. I appreciate the help.

Comment: That won't work. I think it's kind of intractable. The code that's instantiating TheClass is completely outside of a Spring context. I think I'm going to have to do what skaffman suggested. Thanks, though.